# subtracting time in php

Tags: php

My aim is to set a print out data based on a time range in php.
example.. i want a user to only see current content within current time.

```
<?php
$set =  strtotime("2012-02-01");
$t=time();

$a= date('D F d Y', strtotime("2012-02-01"));//set current date
$b= date("D F d Y", strtotime('8 day', $set));
$c= date("D F d Y", strtotime('16 day', $set));
$d= date("D F d Y", strtotime('24 day', $set));
print '<br>'.$a; print '<br>'.$b; print '<br>'.$c; print '<br>'.$d; 

if($t >= $a){ print '<br>1'; }
elseif(($t >= $b&& $t<$c)){ print '<br>2'; }
elseif(($t <= $c&& $t<$d)){ print '<br>3'; }
else { print '<br>default'; }

?>
```

it only prints out 1.

Comment: Search before you ask, use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) class to compare dates

Answer (score 4):

It outputs 1 because you are effectivly doing

```
1329260640 >= "Wed February 01 2012"
```

`$a` is a string and `$t` is an int

When you convert a string to an int it will normally be 0 *(except in the case where the string can be parsed into an int)*

So 1329260640 is more than 0, and hence `$a >= $t`

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing apples and oranges here `$t >= $a`, `$t` is a timestamp whereas `$a` is the string `Wed February 01 2012`. You need to do `if($t >= $set){}`